# Why am I having this white space after the title? How can I remove it?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am having this white space and I am not able to remove this[image]

Comment: Voted to move to [tex.se].

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question, but you probably want to give your figures floating specifier like `\begin{figure}[htbp]` to allow them to be placed in the text flow

Comment: Furthermore, latex has some default limits on what percentage of a page is allowed to be occupied by floats. Without any text, you will probably run into those limits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `\begin{figure}[htbp]`. This should force it to place the figure at the location where it is in the source. This usually works for me.